# How to signal many vue apps from one vue app

Tags: vue.js

Apologies for my noobness.

I'm trying to build a vue app that will have multiple levels of permissions. The app will connect to a page. I would like to give certain users privileges where they can stop access to the page to other users with different permission level who are currently viewing, no matter where they are located

What is the best way to approach this shared state?

I'm guessing I need to set up something that gets checked every second by all instances of the app, when that changes, update the app accordingly.

I'm just completely unsure of which backend to use or how to go about it.

Comment: This is a very broad question, but in wide strokes, you have two primary options. The perhaps easier option is to check permissions whenever the user performs an acton (loading a page, sending in data, etc) and then update the UI accordingly. If for whatever reason, live updates are really crucial even when the user isn't doing anything, you can use websockets.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help. To me more specific this is something that will change on the fly. For instance. Content may become untidy and then an admin user would revoke access to every normal user untill the content was corrected. This may happen multiple times in an hour. The part that I’m not sure of is how to signal all the other users instances of the app that are currently using the web app to view the page to revoke or change the display of the page to “updating’